# Let $A$ matrix with $rank(A) = 2$, Let B, find $a, b, c ,d$ in matrix $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be a $k \times 3$ matrix with $rank(A) = 2$ and let $B = \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 2 & 3 \\
   2 & a & b \\
   3 & c & d 
\end{pmatrix}$. Suppose $AB = 0$. Find $a, b, c, d$.

I tried to do the following: First, I know that $AB=0$, thus meaning that $$Ab_1 = 0, Ab_2 = 0, Ab_3 = 0 \implies$$
$$A\begin{pmatrix}
   1 \\
   2 \\
   3 
\end{pmatrix} = 0, A \begin{pmatrix}
   2 \\
   a \\
   c
\end{pmatrix} = 0, A \begin{pmatrix}
   3 \\
   b \\ 
   d
\end{pmatrix} = 0$$
Which means that $\forall v \in Col(B), Av = 0 \implies v \in Nul(A)$. Also, because $rank(A) = 2$, that implies that $dimNul(A) + rank(A) = n \implies dimNul(A)  +2 = 3 \implies dimNul(A) = 1$, so it appears that the basis for $Col(B)$ is also the part of the basis for $Nul(A)$, which would imply that $dimCol(B) \geq 1$. This is the furthest I got in trying to solve to problem. My intuition points me to believing that $dimCol(B) = 1$, but I can't prove this. Also, I can't seem to understand what kind of linear dependency would allow me to find the values of $a, b, c, d$

Was I on the right track? Also, what information am I missing in order to prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Since the three columns of $B$ belong to $\ker A$ and since this is a $1$-dimensional space, the rank of $B$ must be $1$. Therefore, the second and the third columns must be multiples of the first one.

Comment: Why does it must be 1? I can see why $Col(B) \geq 1$ , but why does it exactly equals 1?

Comment: @0rka Because $B$ is not the null matrix.

Comment: You'll have to excuse me, but I can't see the connection between $B$ not being the null matrix and between $Col(B) = 1$. How does that imply that the rank of $B$ is $1$?

Comment: @0rka Let us see if we're talking about the same thing. I assumed that $\operatorname{Col}(B)$ is the space spanned by the columns of $B$. Am I right?

Comment: Indeed, we talk about the same thing.

Comment: @0rka Then $\operatorname{rank}(B)=\dim\operatorname{Col}(B)$. Since $B$ is not the null matrix, $\operatorname{Col}(B)\neq\{0\}$ and therefore$$\operatorname{rank}(B)=\dim\operatorname{Col}(B)\geqslant1.$$

Comment: I agree. But you stated that $dimCol(B) = 1$. Intuitively I tend to agree, but can't prove why this holds.

Comment: @0rka From $\operatorname{Col}(B)\subset\operatorname{Null}(A)$ and $\dim\operatorname{Null}(A)=1$, you can deduce that $\dim\operatorname{Col}(B)\leqslant1$.

Comment: Oh! Okay, I think I finally got it, took me forever to understand this one. Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: @0rka I'm glad I could help.